# Exposing base CustomRepository method to REST API using Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

In a Spring Boot project I am currently working in, we are using a custom Spring Data JPA base repository, to which we have added a `find()` method which uses our custom querying functionality. Per [the Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories), we have a `CustomRepository` which extends `CrudRepository`, we have a `CustomRepositoryImpl` which extends `SimpleJpaRepository`, and we have `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomRepositoryImpl.class)` in our `@Configuration` class.

So far, so good. On the data side everything is working perfectly. However, we are having some problems exposing our custom functionality to our REST api, using Spring Data REST. There are 2 main problems: 1) actually exposing the custom `find()` method as a REST endpoint, and 2) adding this endpoint to the HAL links on the *specific repository level*. I will go into more detail regarding these two problems.

### 1. Exposing the custom method as a REST endpoint

The problem here is that we obviously wish to do this in a generic way. Right now, if we have, for example, a `Foo` entity, for which we have created a `FooRepository extends CustomRepository<Foo>` interface, we need to create a RestController:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FooRestController {

    @Autowired 
    private FooRepository fooRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/find", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public PagedResources<PersistentEntityResource> findEndPoint(
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> params,
            Pageable pageable,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) throws Exception {

         Page<Foo> page = fooRepository.find(params, pageable);

         return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(page, resourcesAssembler);
    }
}
```

This works as expected. However, suppose we now have another entity called `Bar`, we have to create the exact same method as above, replacing every `Foo` with `Bar` and every `foo` with `bar`. For the purposes of our project, this is an unacceptable violation of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

**To summarize the first problem**: all of our repositories will extend a `CustomRepository`, which has a generic typed `Page<T> find()` method, with T being the repository's entity type parameter. For every repository that extends our `CustomRepository`, we want a REST endpoint to `/api/<the Entity for that repository>/find`. How would we go about doing this, without repeating ourselves for every single repository.

### 2. Adding the custom method REST endpoint to the HAL links

I have currently not found the proper way to add HAL links on the repository level, using Spring Data REST. Currently, I am aware of three options for `ResourceProcessor`, them being `Resource<Entity>`, `RepositoryLinksResource` and `RepositorySearchesResource`.

A `ResourceProcessor<Resource<Entity>>` adds the links returned in the `process` call to every single serialized entity. Given that we are working with a repository-level `find()` method, this is obviously not what we want.

A `ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource>` *seems* to add links only to the root level of the api, though I admit I am not entirely certain what `RepositoryLinksResource` can or cannot do. If I am correct, then that is also not what we want. At the root level, we want to find links to `/api/foo` and `/api/bar`, and only at the `/api/foo` level should we see the `/api/foo/find` link.

A `ResourceProcessor<RepositorySearchesResource>` seems to come closest, as it does add links to the repository level, which is what we are looking for. It is, however, tightly coupled with the Spring mechanic which generates implementations for `findByProperty` methods defined in the repository, meaning that *if you have no `findByProperty` method in any of your repositories, the `process` method will never be called*.

Right now, we have worked around this by hacking into that last option. We have our `FooRestController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositorySearchesResource>`, with the implemented `process(...)` method adding our custom `/api/foo/find` method. We force `process` to be called by adding a `findById(Long id)` method to our `CustomRepository` interface (we can do this because our `CustomRepository` has a `T extends BaseEntity` type parameter, and all of our `BaseEntity`s have a `Long id`). This is a really ugly hack, however, as it adds a redundant method and a redundant REST endpoint in `/api/foo/search/findById`, which gives the exact same result as `/api/foo/{id}`. It also requires us to do the exact same thing for every entity, again grossly violating DRY.

**To summarize the second problem:** given that we have a custom `find()`method in our `CustomRepository` we would like to add an `/api/entity/find` link to the HAL links for every repository extending our `CustomRepository`. This link should be visible on the repository level (`/api/entity`), and we should not need to repeat ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to create an implementation of the repository interface. You extend it with your own interface where you can add custom methods.

```java
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Integer>  { 
   @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.custom = 1 ")      
   List<Entity> find();
}
```

Using `@RepositoryRestController` on a repository creates endpoints for the given repository.
You could also do this manually by replacing foo in the requestmapping with a variable and use that variable for to determine the type of the repository.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{repository}/find")
public Entity find(@PathVariable String repository) {

    Entity entity;

    switch(repository){
        case "Foo": entity = fooRepository.find();
            break;
        case "Bar": entity = barRepository.find();
    }
```

2. For adding custom links the `spring-hateoas` project provides somme nice static imports for that, using generics this should help. For example:

```java
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;    
resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(EntityController.class).getParent(entity.getParentId())).withRel("entityParent"));
```

Comment: While I'm not going to downvote you for this, this is _completely_ beside the point. The implementation of the find() method is _very_ complex, _does_ require a custom implementation and was deliberately left out of the question since it is not a part of the actual problem at hand.

Comment: I updated my answer, I assume the find is not generic?

Comment: It is generic. That's what makes it so complex, that's why it is located in a custom implementation of a _base_ repository.

Comment: So it return a superclass of Foo and Bar so, you should be able to use Page<Super> ?

Comment: No, it returns Foo or Bar. It's method signature is Page<T> find(...), with T being the repository's entity type parameter (T extends BaseEntity).

Answer (score 0):

you should remove produce property. and omit @RequestMapping("/api") Anonation

because spring data rest default add prefix to controller when this defined @RepositoryRestController annotation

i edit some code, like this way:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class FooRestController {

    @Autowired 
    private FooRepository fooRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public PagedResources<PersistentEntityResource> findEndPoint(
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> params,
            Pageable pageable,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) throws Exception {

         Page<Foo> page = fooRepository.find(params, pageable);

         return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(page, resourcesAssembler);
    }
}
```

i'm apply spring boot 2.0 version.